# A way for user to clear DateTimeRow Eureka Forms

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka for my iOS forms. I've got several Datetime rows are initially blank, but once the user taps on the field, the current Date() is filled into the field automatically. See image at the bottom of this post.

The problem here is i need a good way for the user to clear the time, and for the field to revert back to nil after the user has already entered a date.

I was thinking a "clear" button in the keyboard accessory view, but i cant figure out a way to do it with eureka.

Any other implementation suggestions welcomed too!

Here's the code i have for the DateTimeRow

```
<<< DateTimeRow("Tag Name"){ row in
  row.disabled = Condition(booleanLiteral: self.dataEdit?.isLocked ?? false)
} .cellSetup { (cell, row) in
  row.title = "Duty Start Time"
  row.value = self.dataEdit == nil ? nil : self.dataEdit?.dutyStart
  row.dateFormatter?.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
  cell.datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
} .onChange{ row in
  //currently empty
} .onCellHighlightChanged({ (cell, row) in
  // this used to fill in the current date once the user taps on an empty field
  if row.value == nil {
    row.value = Date()
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify accessoryview. first add that class.

```
class CamelAccessoryView : NavigationAccessoryView {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: 44.0))
            autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
            fixedSpace.width = 22.0
            setItems([previousButton, fixedSpace, nextButton, flexibleSpace, clearButton, fixedSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
        }

        var clearButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        var fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

    }
```

in your controller override is such as

```
class RowsExampleViewController: FormViewController {

    override var customNavigationAccessoryView: (UIView & NavigationAccessory)? {
        // The width might not be correctly defined yet: (Normally you can use UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let navView = CamelAccessoryView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44.0))
        navView.previousButton.target = self
        navView.clearButton.target = self
        navView.clearButton.action = "clearAction:"
        return navView
    }
```

it will add a clear button. there will be warning for you "No method declared with Objective-C selector 'clearAction:'.

make a selector to clear your input.

when clicked the function get your input such as

```
let yourInput = self.form.rowBy(tag: "Tag Name") as! DateTimeRow
yourInput.value = "" // just clear it
```

update:::

try to change your func like that.

```
@objc func clearAction(button: UIBarButtonItem){
    guard let currentRow = tableView?.findFirstResponder()?.formCell()?.baseRow else { return }
    currentRow.baseValue = nil
    currentRow.updateCell()
}
```

if this not works try second option for making a global tagNo variable to get which row has been selected.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for your answer! Works perfectly, i'll just add that objc selector should be navView.clearButton.action = #selector(self.clearAction)

Comment: Sorry, follow on question. Is there a way for the clearAction method to know which row was it that was cleared? With this solution, now all my fields in that form has a clear button. Since they all have clear buttons, I'll like to know which row was it that called the clear method, and i'll only clear that particular field

Comment: you can make a global variable to detect which row has been focus. in clear function switch the value and make just it clear.